# Relative pronoun 'who' or 'which' when referring to article by authors' names

Tags: grammar

In an academic paper, when I refer to an article by author's name and publication year, then use a relative pronoun, should I use 'who' or 'which?'

For example,

> We referred to the method proposed by Smith and  Johnson (2004) who suggested blah-blah.

Comment: I'd use _who_, but probably this question is a better fit for ELU.SE.

Comment: I think it is appropriate for Academia.SE because it involves a very specific feature of language rarely if ever seen outside of academic writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends entirely on the subject of your subordinate (relative) clause.

If the authors are the subjects of the subordinate clause, use *who*. E.g.

> Many postmodernists reacted angrily to the stunt pulled by Sokal (1996), *who* they felt had acted unethically in an effort to discredit their field.

If the paper or text is the subject of the subordinate clause, use *which*. E.g.

> If you want to improve your mathematical writing, I recommend carefully examining Halmos (1974) *which* as a text manages the difficult feat of combining  scrupulous rigorous with broad accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you'll need *who*, as you wrote:

> We referred to the method proposed by Smith and Johnson (2004) who suggested blah-blah.

Here's an example with *which*:

> We compared our results with those of the method proposed by Smith and Johnson (2004), which is similar to our method except in how xxx is handled.

Comment: In your second example, note that the subject of the subordinate clause is actually "method" not "Smith and Johnson (2004)" -- though still a correct answer to the question because I realize the OP specified only the word order not role.

Comment: @Corvus - Yes.  I wanted to show the OP how it works, with a couple of simple examples.  But perhaps the OP will want the full grammatical explanation.  I suppose everyone learns differently.